# get data from SQLite acording to a datagridview row selection

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, combobox

I have a SQLite db and working on a frontend coding with vb.net.
I populate a combobox with Patient data. On SelectedIndexChanged event y get the patient Id and fill a datagridview with studies result.
Now when the user select some rows from it I would like to retrieve some other data and show it on a chart.

I'm using CurrentCellChanged event from datagridview. The first problem is that as soon as the grid is created it fire CurrentCellChanged event and there is no data right now, so if I try to use dgvIzq.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString it fire an exeption.
So, I add an if statement:

```
        If (dgvIzq.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            LoaddBNoise("IZQUIERDO", dgvIzq.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString)
        End If
```

but I get the exception:
"El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección." dgvIzq.RowCount return 1

So, what is the way to get the funtionality I want working ok?

Thank!

Comment: If you're going to be indexing `SelectedRows` then surely you should be testing whether `SelectedRows.Count` is greater than zero.  Who cares how many rows there are if none of them are selected?  I suspect that you don't know what `SelectedRows` actually means.  It's the rows actually highlighted by the user.  You probably want `CurrentRow` rather than `SelectedRows(0)`, but it's not completely clear.

Comment: By the way, if you are receiving an error message in a language other than English, please provide the English translation, rather than requiring everyone who views it to translate it for themselves.